# Область видимости в Javascript

Tags: javascript

Есть такой код. Как из функции  `$.ajax({....success: function(msg){` 
передать msg в html : var1

```
CKEDITOR.dialog.add('insertGoodlink', function (editor) {
    return {
        title: 'Link Properties',
        minWidth: 400,
        minHeight: 200,
        onShow: function () {
            var selectedtext = editor.getSelection().getSelectedText();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/back/articles/e.php",
                async: false,
                data: "action=search_search_from_CK&search_name=" + selectedtext + "&lang_id=1",
                success: function (msg) {
                    var1 = msg;
                }
            });
        },

        contents: [{
            id: 'general',
            label: 'Settings',
            elements: [{
                type: 'html',
                html: var1
            }, ]
        }]
    };
});
```

Comment: Порешайте что-то с форматировнием кода.. код небольшой но абсолютно нечитаем.

В любом случае непонятно зачем вам нужны массивы если вы в них пишите по 1ому объекту

Answer (score 1):

Вы абсолютно не понимаете, о чем спрашиваете. И не понимаете как работает JS.

Вы вызываете некую функцию: `CKEDITOR.dialog.add` и вторым параметром задаете функцию.

Тут стоит остановится поподробней, мы передаём лямбда-выражение. Это функция, которая еще не вызывается, но можно вызвать.

Идём дальше, эта функция возвращает хеш, в одном ключе из которых есть опять же лямда-выражение: `onShow: function()...`

И дело тут вовсе не в области видимости, просто эти части кода исполняются в разное время.

На момент возвращения хеша, строка: `var1 = msg;` еще не отработала.

Comment: Я тут вообще ничего не пишу,
это стандартный код `CKEditora` по добавлению плагина.
Единственно что я добавил - это вызов ажакса, так как у них сюда можно прописывать только статику, типа html: "Bla Bla", а мне нужно кинуть текст из ажакса. Вот меня и интересует, как тут вывернуться.

Comment: Извернуться - сначала сделать запрос, а потом добавлять плагин.

Comment: Тогда при повторном открытии окна ажакс запрос не выполняется. он должен быть именно в onShow: function () {

Answer (score 0):

Быдлокод.

Зачем все лепить в один ретурн ?:))) Вы бы еще продолжили ВЕСЬ JS код вот так вот )))
Такой чтобы он длиииинный получился и совершенно нечитабелен :)
Я, примерно, так писал первую самую программу на C#.... получилось длинно, заумно и не понятно :)

1. На каждую переменную внутри объекта необходимо сделать функции get и set
2. Построить одну (а лучше статический класс), котроый будет выполнять ajax нужный )
3. Если Вам нужно вернуть объект - так стройте этот объект, а не лепите все в один return.
4. А представьте, что будет, когда Вам необходимо будет строить динамический массив ? :D

Почитайте про паттерный проектирования. Вам это необходимо... да и потом таких вопросов задавать не будете :) ... Потратьте 3 часа своего времени (хотя, думаю, больше понадобится) и все станет ясно :)

А еще лучше (исключительно мое мнение), за основу построения ООП-шной структуры кода возьмите какой-нибудь олковый фреймворк типа qooxdoo. Сложный в понимании в начале, но потом получается писать с сумасшедшей скоростью....

Comment: писать с сумасшедшей скоростью != хорошая структура кода

Как-раз таки в фреймворках довольно часто встречаются "нипанятные" места, какие-то хаки либо решение проблем скорости работы.

В коде "обычного смертного" - ИМХО этого лучше не допускать. Вернее это есть необходимость, но когда речь идет уже о **релизе**.

Вообщем тут нужно базы учить. Кстати - ТС посмотрите [это](http://hashcode.ru/questions/66586/паттерны-javascript), быть может, для вас, как-раз, будет актуально

Comment: Пример самой простой фишки данного фреймворка: например, при создании property класса, автоматом идет проверка их типов, создаются необходимые функции типа get, set , можно сразу же вешать листенеры на изменения их состояния и т.д. Это я и подразумеваю под сумасшедшей скоростью за счет уменьшения в разы кол-ва кода :)